# Node.js PATCH request with If-Match header

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https

This is a simple question for which I've not been able to find an answer.

In Node.js, as I'm forming a PATCH request, I'd like to set the if-match header to *. Is this how I'd do it? Would this work?

```
headers: {
    'if-match': '*'
}
```

Comment: Have you just tried it?

Comment: Yeah, I did--but I failed to immediately follow up with an answer to my own question. The if-match header works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it works.**

Here is a simple example.

Client Node.js program:

```
const http = require('http');
const agent = new http.Agent();
let req = http.request({
  agent: agent,
  port: 3000,
  path: '/',
  method: 'PATCH',
  headers: {
    'if-match': '*'
  }
});
req.end();
```

Server Node.js program (could be other server-side technology as well):

```
const http = require('http');

let server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.url);
  console.log(req.method);
  console.log(req.headers);
  res.end();
});

server.listen(3000, function() { console.log("Server Listening on http://localhost:3000/"); });
```

The printed result in console is:

```
/
PATCH
{ 'if-match': '*',
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-length': '0' }
```

You can see that both `PATCH` and `if-match` header is received in server side.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. This is pretty much what I ended up trying shortly after posting this question.